# Angular + rxjs: No provider for Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement a service-component communication in angular, when service holds a value and component subscribes to it change. I'm using rxjs Subscription, but I'm getting

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Subscription!
```

Here is what I'm doing in a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class PracticeContextService {
  practice: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public practiceSelected$ = this.practice.asObservable();

 setPractice(providerId: string) {
   this.practice.next({ providerId: providerId });
 }

 getPractice(): Observable<any> {
   return this.practice.asObservable();
 }
}
```

and in the component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { PracticeContextService } from '../practice-context.service';

@Component({
  selector : 'practice-context-selector',
  templateUrl : './practice-context-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls : ['./practice-context-selector.component.css']
})

export class PracticeContextSelectorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  practice: string;

  constructor(private context: PracticeContextService,
          private subscription: Subscription) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.context.practiceSelected$.subscribe(
      practice => {
        this.practice = practice;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Component and service are than bundled into module, which is later injected into another module.

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';

import { PracticeContextSelectorComponent } from './practice-context-selector/practice-context-selector.component';
import { PracticeContextService } from './practice-context.service';

@NgModule({
  imports : [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations : [
    PracticeContextSelectorComponent
  ],
  providers : [
    PracticeContextService,
  ],
  exports: [
    PracticeContextSelectorComponent
  ]
})

export class PracticeContextModule {}
```

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: If you have a constructor parameter in a class instantiated by Angulars DI, then there has to be a matching provider. What's the purpose of this parameter in `constructor(private context: PracticeContextService,
          private subscription: Subscription)`?

Comment: Subscription is not for for DI, import it like `import { Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';`.

Comment: @lyubimov-roman I'm actually doing this import in a component. If I don't have to wire up this dependency to a component in constructor, than what is the correct way to use? I'm asking cause I found a handful of examples utilizing this approach but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Why are you importing it in the constructor, what is a purpose of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service, you could **first of all** change rxjs imports like this :

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

I already had an issue when importing { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'. Now I am careful with this :P ! (I should maybe dig further to find out what really happens behind the scene.)

**Then**, as already said Lyubimov Roman in its comment above, you should not import rxjs *subscription* through the constructor. I don't understand your answer to Lyubimov's comment. Could you please provide us the examples you mention in order to let us figure out what is intended ?

If you need to use an *subscription* object in your component, just import it like this :

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: But better to import it separatly if you don't want to import the whole module.

Comment: Indeed, I finally realized that I can declare it in the part where I declare types, like
    subscription: Subscription;
instead of constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Ha! I know exactly what happened to @vitalym because I just did the exact same thing. I intended to declare my Subscription above my constructor but with all the `private` declarations, they look the same! lol

Answer (score 21):

Just remove `private subscription: Subscription` from constructor and put it in attribute of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from constructor and declare it out side.

```
private _Subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when I was new to angular and faced this issue multiple times and couldn't understand what the issue was. So to start with make sure you have the imports properly declared as `import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';`

For me the error was **Null Injection Error. No Provider for Subscription**.

Initially, I started declaring the **Subscription** inside the constructor as :

```
constructor(){private activatedsubscription:Subscription}
```

This wouldn't work, as I later realized that the reason why it was Null Injection, was because it was declared inside the constructor, where as it should be declared outside the constructor as a property or Globally inside the Class as:

```
export class Component implements OnInit{
activatedsubscription:Subscription
}
```

**Note**: Make sure that you unsubscribe the from the Subscription when destroying the Component by calling **OnDestroy**. Otherwise you would have **memory leak**.

Comment: well done and thanks for saving me :), Yes OnDestroy is must

Answer (score 0):

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'
public subscription : Subscription = new Subscription();
this one works in angular

Answer (score -1):

i was started with make sure you have the imports properly declared as

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'
```

then i use it as

```
public subscription : Subscription = new Subscription();
```